# Wordpress redirection conflicts - htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

(My old site was in the directory `/dotclear/index.php/`.)

I want to do some custom redirections to new pages, and redirect all the rest to the homepage.

Currently, the redirections that I have specified all redirect to the homepage, while the pages I have not specified redirect to the same URL without prefix.

Without a redirect 301 rule, `/dotclear/index.php/somepage` redirects to `/somepage` and I would like it to redirect to `/`

With a redirect 301 rule, `/doctlear/index/oldpage` redirects to `/` and I would like it to redirect to `/newpage`

Here's what I've tried.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
Options -Indexes


Redirect 301 /dotclear/index.php / 
Redirect 301 /dotclear/index.php/oldpage /new-page //redirects to home but shoudln't
Redirect 301 /dotclear/index.php/anotheroldpage /anothernewpage //redirects to home but shouldn't
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems with this approach:

1. Doing redirect after WP default rules
2. Mixing `Redirect` with `mod_rewrite` rules
3. Have redirect rules in wrong order

With all the fixes, you can use these directives in your .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^dotclear/index\.php$ / [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^dotclear/index\.php/oldpage/?$ /new-page [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^dotclear/index\.php/anotheroldpage/?$ /anothernewpage [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing to avoid old cache.

Comment: worked out perfectly. Why exactly is it a bad idea to mic Redirect and mod_rewrite ?

Comment: `Redirect` with `mod_rewrite` are from different Apache modules and Apache runs them at different order so you can never be sure of order of execution of your rules.